# Как в Laravel сделать не запускаемым одну из таблиц миграции?

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно сделать одну из таблиц не запускаемым, так как будто его нет совсем, 
удалять не хочу потом пригодится но сейчас нужно чтобы эта конкретная миграция не запускалась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закомментируйте код в классе или вынесите в другую папку, например `database/disabled-migrations`.